# How browser defines, which characters in source HTML, to collapse to single whitespace in rendered HTML? How about \s regex?

Tags: javascript, html

I want a function, which will check, if a text node will be collapsed into single whitespace by browser, in the rendered HTML:

```
function isSingleWhitespace(node) {
    var spacesCollapsed = node.textContent.replace(/[ \n\r\t]+/g, '');  // What about \s ?
    return spacesCollapsed.length === 0;
}
```

Which characters become collapsed to single whitespace when HTML is rendered by browser, does `\s` class suit to find them? As a part of larger regexp?

What about stuff like `&zwsp;`? Does `\s` include it? I need to account everything that is not rendered by browser. Regexp  solution is not the only acceptable, actually, if that collapsing-to-single-whitespace algorithm has complex specification, which can not be resolved finely, using only RegExp (like true, "hard-core" email validation), then where can I find that **algorithm specification**? Any link to any implementation, flowchart, a listing of char codes, anything that specifies, **how browser defines, which characters will be collapsed to single-whitespace**. At least, what to query in google, really.

My use case is: I want to **translate caret position** between **rendered html** units and **html source** units, for wysiwyg editor being built on contenteditable, because when the user presses backspace or delete, it should silently skip those characters, and remove visible one.

Comment: Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp): `\s` is equivalent to `[ \f\n\r\t\v​\u00a0\u1680​\u180e\u2000​-\u200a​\u2028\u2029\u202f\u205f​\u3000\ufeff]` If you'd like to filter out more Unicode characters, you'll have to add them manually.

Comment: Could you explain your use case in a little more detail?

Comment: `&zwsp;` is not a "character"; it's an HTML escape sequence which represents the specific Unicode character in question. For example, you would never find this in `textContent`; it would already have been interpreted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### As for *which character are collapsed*

[space character in HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/infrastructure.html#common-parser-idioms) are defined:

> The space characters, for the purposes of this specification, are U+0020 SPACE, U+0009 CHARACTER TABULATION (tab), U+000A LINE FEED (LF), U+000C FORM FEED (FF), and U+000D CARRIAGE RETURN (CR).

so any **subsequent** character from this group is collapsed and leading/trailing trimmed **in most cases** (1), so your regexp seems fine.

#### As for *is there common API to get the "rendered" content*

Seems you are reading `textContent` - it provides actual "source" formatting.

If you used [**`innerText`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/innerText) instead, you'd get what you probably want - provided you are in DOM context and in capable environment. See [The poor, misunderstood innerText](http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText/) by Kangax.

---

(1) behaviour depends on CSS and / or node type: for instance `<pre>` or anything with `white-space: pre` keeps white space while `<p>` or anything with `white-space: normal` gets subsequent space characters collapsed and trimmed.

Try example below:

```html
<p id="p1"> 1  2   3  </p>
<pre><script>
document.write( p1.innerText.split(''))
</script></pre>

<p id="p2" style="white-space: pre"> 1  2   3  </p>
<pre><script>
document.write( p2.innerText.split(''))
</script></pre>
```

Comment: So, the innerText should not be used actually, it has poor support across browsers. By the way, I'm also making a wysiwyg editor using contenteditable, like someone in the article. I really need innerText, but firefox supports it only from version 45. Pity that text nodes doesn't have innerHTML property. I think `\s` regexp will be most adequate solution, added that I fully control the contents of wysiwyg document.

Comment: What would an `innerHTML` property on text nodes even mean, since text nodes by definition don't contain HTML?

Comment: Well, in my case it'd be great if they mean like wrap that text into span and get it's innerHTML, then... wait I minute, what could stop me from actually doing this... I don't even need to insert that temporary element into dom, I must try that now

Comment: Doesn't work, innerHTML returns all whitespaces and crs included. It was my misunderstanding of how the property works. So, `\s` is the only way left.